# Shell Script variable with "", (), {} or both together for value with space

Tags: bash, shell

What is the difference of using "" or {} for a variable in shell script

```
PATH="\home\user\test dir"
```

When to use

```
"$PATH"
$(PATH)
${PATH}
"${PATH}"
```

Any other use case or way to define this variable ?

Comment: `$(PATH)` is not a variable, it's command substitution.

Comment: @RajavelD Note that backslash is one of the characters that can have a special meaning inside double-quotes; if you want to include them literally in the string, it's generally safer to use single-quotes around them (e.g. `PATH='\home\user\test dir'`). But backslash isn't the standard unix path delimiter, it's forward-slash (e.g. `PATH='/home/user/test dir'`). Also, `PATH` is the variable that controls where the system looks for command files; if that's not the meaning you want, use a different variable name (preferably one in lower- or mixed-case to avoid conflicts with other special vars).

Comment: @Rajavel: You can shorten `${foo}` to `$foo`, if no other character which could be interpreted as part of the variable name, follows it. If you are unsure, just use the curly braces all the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here comes a sample code where `{ }` is mandatory.

```
var=123
echo "${var}xx" # 123xx
echo "$var"xx   # 123xx but not the proper way
echo "$varxx"   # nothing, unknown variable varxx
```

And `$( )` is a Command Substitution: `"$(cmd "foo bar")"` causes the command 'cmd' to be executed with the argument 'foo bar' and `"$(..)"` will be replaced by the output. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002 and http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution

Always quote your variables.

Learn how to quote properly in shell, it's very important :

> "Double quote" every literal that contains spaces/metacharacters and *every* expansion: `"$var"`, `"$(command "$var")"`, `"${array[@]}"`, `"a & b"`. Use `'single quotes'` for code or literal `$'s: 'Costs $5 US'`, `ssh host 'echo "$HOSTNAME"'`. See
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes
> http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Arguments
> http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/words

Comment: How to define if we use $PATH in if condition which contain space ?

Comment: With the mandatory quotes: `PATH="/foo bar:/bin:/sbin"` ...